# Magento 2 blank product price and image after data migration?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.0, magento2-migration-tool

I have migrated data from `magento1.9.0.1` to `magento2` in admin panel.

**I am able to see product and its details but when I edit any product it shows only product name and sku other fields are blank.**

Suggest me some solution.